# Writing a user specified folder structure to csv in Python

Tags: python, csv, directory

I am trying to write a python script that will take in a user specified directory and then write the contents of that directory to a csv file. The challenge I am facing is to write the folder structure to the csv in a certain format. The format I need is shown below:
[image: Sample Folder Structure]

I've tried using os.walk(dir) to list the directories and files but I'm having trouble writing to the csv in the above format.

I've also found some code that creates a nested dictionary out of a given folder structure but I'm finding it very difficult to navigate through this nested structure and write the rows in the way that I need.

If anyone has an easier approach to accomplishing this task it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you obliged to use csv? There are other formats which are more convenient to hold structured data. Like JSON or pickle.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately the final format needs to be in csv...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the code that does the job:

```
import os
import csv

data = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for f in files:
        l = root.split('/') + [f]
        data.append(l)

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for d in data:
        writer.writerow(d)
```

If you're on windows, replace `split('/')` with `split('\\')`

Comment: Thanks Anton. I was able to arrive at something similar using os.walk. The main problem with this method is that it leaves out empty folders which I need to write to the csv as well. Additionally, I couldn't find an easy way to remove all the duplicate values of each folder...